# Connect 4k display to the 2013 Mac Pro?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, mac-pro

I have an Apple Cinema Display circa 2007. It's attached to my 2013 Mac Pro via a HDMI/USB breakout cable connected to one of the Thunderbolt 2 ports and into one of the D300s.

The display has recently begun showing a sort of "ghost image" of closed windows and such, so I have started to look at the ASUS PA329Q as a potential replacement.

My question is:

Since it has a miniDisplayPort 1.2 port, can I plug a cable directly from my thunderbolt port to this port?
    If so:

- Will it drive the full 3840 x 2160 without problem?
- Will that single cable make the USB ports on the monitor work?

Comment: https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-twelve-core-2.7-xeon-e5-gray-black-cylinder-late-2013-specs.html - 3 x 4k displays, but idk the cabling required

Comment: I've edited your question and in the process removed the "side question". Besides the fact this site works best when each question is focused on a single issue, that part of your post was also off-topic as it was primarily opinion based. After all, no-one here is going to know if the ghosting was always present and you just didn't notice it. All the best with your main question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will drive the full 3840 x 2160 without problem. However, it will only be carrying video signal, not data or power. As such, it will not make the USB ports on the monitor work.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! Is this a limitation of the monitor, the cable, or the Mac?

Comment: Also, can I get USB on the monitor by connecting a USB to the Mac? Or is that something's that's up to the monitor and may be dependant on that?

Comment: If the monitor had a Thunderbolt connection then you would be able to use a Thunderbolt cable and get data along with the video signal.

Comment: It is really up to how the USB ports are set up on the monitor as to whether or not that will work.

Answer (score 0):

All Thunderbolt ports are also DisplayPort ports, but not all DisplayPort-capable ports carry Thunderbolt. The six shaved-squared-corners Thunderbolt 2 ports on your Mac Pro actually start out as Mini DisplayPort, and appeared under that name as video outputs a full year before we saw our first Thunderbolt logo on anything.

If your new display just has regular DisplayPort inputs, a simple cable with MiniDP on one end and DP on t'other will be more than adequate.